# Making 2 by 2 grid using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make 2 by 2 customized grid using flexbox but I cannot make it work currently.

Here is what I am trying to do.
[image]

```
Hight of 1 and 2 is smaller than that of 3 and 4. 
And width of 1 and 3 is wider than 2 and 4.
```

I tried doing it in following Fiddle, but it is not working as I intend to do so. Any help is appreciated.
https://jsfiddle.net/jewcvLs5/1/

Comment: please check this out if you need it like this https://jsfiddle.net/7qhj8dat/

Comment: @talentedandrew I want something like this. But is there a way to make this more dynamic? I mean, you are giving hard numbers on width and height now. I wonder if there's a way to use something like flex: 2 0px. I don't know which is better practice tho

Comment: you can give height, width in % so that it can be responsive also

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox cannot do this natively without additional "row" wrappers.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  background: #c0ffee;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.row {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  order: 1;
}
.child:first-child {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1 0 66.6666%;
}
.child:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 0 33.333%;
}
.first .child:first-child {
  height: 75px;
}
.second .child:first-child {
  height: 150px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    display: contents;
  }
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .child:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row first">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row second">
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, ths presents problems if, at certain breakpoints, we wish to re-order the children **between** wrapping rows.

There is a new CSS `display` property `contents` [**[MDN LInk]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) which allows us to "unwrap" the elements as though they wrapper were not there.

Unfortunately, on FF (37+) supports it as of the date of writing but I leave this example here (and [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LZpLPX)) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#wrapper .one,
#wrapper .three {
  flex: 100 0 34%;
}
#wrapper .two,
#wrapper .four {
  flex: 1 0 34%;
}
.one::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10%;
}
.three::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30%;
}

/*properties below are just for cosmetics*/
.one {
  background: violet;
}
.two {
  background: orange;
}
.three {
  background: limegreen;
}
.four {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
.one::before {
  border: 2px solid maroon;
}
.three::before {
  border: 2px solid navy;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='one'></div>
  <div class='two'></div>
  <div class='three'></div>
  <div class='four'></div>
</div>
```

We want the flexboxes to wrap into two rows so we use `flex` and `row wrap` on the wrapper.

Because the `flex-basis` is 34% only two items will fit on a line. The first and third div have a much larger `flex-grow` factor so they will take up virtually all of the remaining space. This results in a first "column" that is approximately twice as wide as the second "column".

To force the heights of the rows we use a `pseudo-element` on the first and third div. Vertical margins and paddings are based on the *width* of the parent. Because the first and third div have the same width we can make the second "row" three times as large by making the relevant pseudo-element three times as large.